# Ubuntu 22.10 RTL8821CE no longer shows up in additional drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.10

Today I upgraded to 22.10. I know it is kind of a rash decision. I should've waited longer. But this purged my WI-fi driver(RTL8821CE) and now it doesn't show up in the additional drivers like in 22.04, so I don't have Wi-fi connection. I'm using my phone's USB thetering. I enabled the 22.04 community repo in Other Software but it didn't help. Any other ideas? What is the best place where I can request to be included in the new repos?

Edit:
Wi-fi never worked for me out of the box, even in newest kernel with Arch. Only on Ubuntu (and derivatives) when I enable the RTL8821CE(dkms) in the additional drivers.

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
        Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
        Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Support for RTL8821CE was added to the Linux kernel in version 5.9. You should no longer need any special packages for that hardware (if that's really what you have). Troubleshoot your hardware normally, not assuming a repo is the issue. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370462/how-to-troubleshoot-wifi

Comment: It never worked out of the box for me, even in the newest kernel on Arch. Only on Ubuntu (and derivatives) when I enable the RTL8821CE(dkms) in the additional drivers.

Comment: When you wish to add additional information, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1436565/edit) instead of commenting. Comments are how we help you to improve your question until it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please join the bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8821ce/+bug/1993955)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem this evening. Installing the driver manually worked for me. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071334)